Extension problem for complex value real-linear functionals
I study Hahn-Banach theorem now, it implies any linear functionals can be extented to the whole space with same operator norm. If we consider a complex valued linear operator $f_0$ over a subset $E$ of real linear space $X$, i.e. $f_0:E\mapsto \mathbb{C}$, is there corrsponding extension theorem?
I have tried applying real Hahn-Banach theorem to real part and imaginary part of $f_0$, so we have a complex valued real linear operator defined on whole $X$, and easily to see $\|f_0\|\leq\|f\|$. But other direction has some issue, I found this extension maintains operator norms of real part and imaginary part of $f$ separately, so we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
|f(x)|=\sqrt{(\mathrm{Re}f(x))^2+\mathrm{Im}f(x))^2}&\leq\sqrt{\|\mathrm{Re}f\|^2+\|\mathrm{Im}f\|^2}\|x\|\\
&=\sqrt{\|\mathrm{Re}f_0\|^2+\|\mathrm{Im}f_0\|^2}\|x\|
\end{aligned}
$$
the last equality because of real Hahn-Banach theorem. And we can't obtain
$$\sqrt{\|\mathrm{Re}f_0\|^2+\|\mathrm{Im}f_0\|^2}=\|f_0\|$$
in general, so we can't achieve our results.
I noticed the proof of complex Hahn-Banach theorem relies on a complex linear functional $f$ can be express as
$$f(x)=\mathrm{Re}f(x)-i\mathrm{Re}f(ix)$$
so maybe we can't extension complex valued real linear operator? Is there any counterexample?
Any hints, proof, counterexamples and references are very apperaciate!

Instead of $\mathbb C$ as target space, you might as well consider $\mathbb R^n$ (with the Euclidean norm) and ask for a vector valued Hahn Banach theorem. The linked wikipedia suggests that there is an extension with the same norm, if the target is finite dimensional. You could look up the references, or just go through the standard proof of Hahn-Banach and see whether having $\mathbb R^n$-valued maps creates any trouble at all.

@JanBohr I don't see the claim on the linked page that $\mathbb R^n$ with the Euclidean norm has the metric extension theorem. I doubt very much that this is true.

@Jochen Indeed, reading the wikipedia article more carefully suggests the opposite of what I claimed above - apologies for the confusion, and thanks for pointing that out. By the last theorem on that page, we'd need a linear isometry of $(\mathbb R^2,|\cdot|2)$ with $C(T,||\cdot||\infty)=(\mathbb R^2,|\cdot|_\infty)$ (where $T$ is a $2$-point space). But of course, there is no such isometry.
